# Jquery на Android

Tags: jquery, android

Jquery на Android работает?
сделал приложение на Андроид с jquery, но он чета тупит

подключаю вот так

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Может надо атрибут

```
        language="JavaScript"
```

Comment: Вы используете обычную библиотеку или [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: обычную))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С подключением jQuery проблем нет, но чистый jQuery мало пригоден. Есть нюансы с tap, swype и т.д., которые в jQuery не работают. Есть более подходящие специализированные фреймворки, включающие в том числе и готовые виджеты:

1. [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)
2. [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/)
3. [Sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch)
4. etc

Плюс [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) если нужны хардварные фичи (акселерометр, камера...).

Comment: я вообще не полностью приложение делаю, а только 3 страницы через HTML и JavaScript, у меня все ок работает в браузере, но потом когда его компилируют и т.п эти страницы начинаю пахать не правильно и проблемы связаны с jQuery

Comment: не знаю что имеется в виду под "компилируют", но без теста хотя бы на эмуляторе понять в чем проблема не получится. А это значит за [Android SDK][1],
проверять на различных версиях андроида (2.1+), т.к. это только пока 3 страницы...

Если глючит непосредственно js, то можно воспользоваться [JS Console][2], тут [туториал на youtube][3], для удаленной отладки (и на эмуляторе и на реальном девайсе).

[1]:http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
[2]:http://jsconsole.com/
[3]:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSH392Gxaho

Comment: Android SDK - это эмулятор?

Comment: В SDK входит кроме всего прочего и эмулятор. Вот [тут][1] неплохая статья.

[1]:http://blog.regolit.com/2012/02/10/android-programming-1-sdk-intro

Answer (score 0):

jquery работает в браузере.
автор вопроса, видимо, делает что-то более специфичное.
со своей стороны, рекомендую пощупать уже упомянутый выше PhoneGap - как самый простой путь скомпилировать проект на HTML/CSS/JS в приложение для андроида